# Shifting Fields Up After Suppressing in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports

Does anyone have any ideas how to shift up the remaining fields after suppressing?  I am suppressing a numeric field in the footer of a report and would like to shift up the remaining fields below it so it doesn't look 'blank'.

Any and all help appreciated!

JFV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the numeric field in its own section, then conditionally suppress the section.

Comment: I thought that's the way I needed to go.  I just didn't want to add yet another section!  Thanks for the help!